# A Regex which represents a space followed by a period?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following statements :

`Regex.IsMatch("a .e", "\.")` returns `true` as expected.
`Regex.IsMatch("a .e", "\b\.")` returns `false` while it should be returning `true`.

Tried a few other instances and found that `"\b\."` doesn't work as expected. Whats wrong here? Could you please tell me how do I create a Regex which represents a space followed by a period?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx): _Assertion `\b`: The match must occur on a boundary between a `\w` (alphanumeric) and a `\W` (nonalphanumeric) character._ `\.` is not alphanumeric

Comment: Try `@"\s\."` for any whitespace character followed by a period.

Comment: `"\."` and `"\b\."` don't actually compile in C# - the `\.` is not a valid escape sequence. Is this your actual code?

Comment: I actually tried [regex]::ismatch("a .e","\b\.") on powershell..translated to C# to post question here..(thought C# would have a more active community to reply)

Answer (score 1):

Space followed by a period:

```
" \\."
```

Note that you need to escape the '\' with which you escape the '.'.

Or alternatively

```
@" \."
```

Comment: `Note that you need to escape the '\' with which you escape the '.'.` Not if you use the verbatim `@`

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that the patterns for the regex are strings..
And strings in c# have special characters that need to be escaped.. the slash is one of it..
try..

`Regex.IsMatch("a .e", "\\b\\.")`